# Query on Ratchet Socket

Tags: sockets, ratchet

- I am using Ratchet Socket. I have established a new server connection and I want to stop server from running. In this scenario I have IP(Hostname) and port with me, So how can I stop that?
- Is it possible to make a server connection that never ends?
- When I make a server connection, first day the data output is perfect from DB, But on second day, the error is generated as "Connection is closed by foreign host". But still I can connect to that port.

**Code**

```
<?php 
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use MyApp\Chat;
use React\EventLoop\Factory;
use React\ZMQ\Context;
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/src/MyApp/Chat.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new Chat(), 
    6666
);

$server->run();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1.

> I am using Ratchet Socket. I have established a new server connection
>   and I want to stop server from running. In this scenario I have
>   IP(Hostname) and port with me, So how can I stop that?

I assume that you currently run your Ratchet server by running it as a php script in a terminal window or screen.
eg: `php push-server.php`

Once you stop running the script your server will stop.

2.

> Is it possible to make a server connection that never ends?

Yes, if your php script stops working from the terminal, you have to manually restart it. Its better to use a program like Supervisor (A Process Control System) which is recommended by Ratchet.

Check this link for more info http://supervisord.org/installing.html

The supervisord service will monitor your php script and will automatically restart it if it crashes which is suited for production environments.

3.

> When I make a server connection, first day the data output is perfect
>   from DB, But on second day, the error is generated as "Connection is
>   closed by foreign host". But still I can connect to that port.

This is quite common and I've noticed it too. It usually happens when the server is heavily loaded or times out. Your JavaScript should check for this message and re-initiate a new connection if you see this message. You can also get it to try again after a random timer as well.

**Edits**

Also the __construct method for the Ratchet\Server\IoServer requires 3 prams, of which the 3rd one being optional. The first and second need to be objects of MessageComponentInterface and ServerInterface.

```
public function __construct(MessageComponentInterface $app, ServerInterface $socket, LoopInterface $loop = null) {
```

The way you instantiate the `IoServer` seems incorrect.

Comment: 1) I am using Framework and I have initiated an action to Start a server connection to Port. So I am not using terminal to start a server connection. Is there any other way to stop server connection with PHP?

2) We are using socket service only to transmit data from DB and between server to mobile Apps. We are not using any Javascript for this, As we don't display anything in Frontend. If i print any static data, it is returned successfully even after few days. But data from DB using Mysql closes the connection

Comment: I might have to see more code in order to help you. Also if you are not running a script in the terminal where are you running this code from?: ```$server->run();```. You have to have a script listening for any incoming messages on port 6666 from your webApp/Framework.

Comment: Nope. There is no issue in Code. I guess  the issue is with timeout. The timeout may be in Mysql or Socket. I can't able to figure out.